# How to fix Out Of Bounds Exception error?

Tags: java

I wrote in an exam a backtracking code that moving between cell and counting paths, the conditions are if the next cell is i+k or j+k or i-k or j-k.
the code somehow is still going out of bounds even due I tried to prevent it from doing so.

I tried adding fixing the code by adding +1 in the checking valid move in the "if" conditions.

```java
public class Test3
{
    public static int howManyPaths(int [][] mat)
    {
        return howManyPaths(mat,0,0,0);
    }

    private static int howManyPaths(int [][] mat, int i, int j, int count)
    {
        if(i == mat.length-1){return count;}
        if(j == mat[i].length-1){return howManyPaths(mat,i+1,0,count);}
        count = pathCount(mat,i,j);
        return howManyPaths(mat,i,j+1,count);
    }

    private static int pathCount(int [][] mat, int i, int j)
    {
        int k = mat[i][j];        
        if(i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] == mat[i+k][j] && i+k < mat.length-1){
            return 1 + pathCount(mat,i+k,j);}

        if(j < mat[i].length-1 && mat[i][j]==mat[i][j+k] && j+k < mat[i].length-1){
            return 1 + pathCount(mat,i,j+k);}

        if(i > 0 && mat[i][j]==mat[i-k][j] && i-k > 0){
            return 1 + pathCount(mat,i-k,j);}

        if(j > 0 && mat[i][j]==mat[i][j-k] && j-k > 0){
            return 1 + pathCount(mat,i,j-k);}
        return 1;
    }
}
```

the expected is how many paths and the actual results are "out of bounds".

**Edited with the fixet code still not working**

Comment: First step: understand what a Out Of Bounds Exception is. Once you do, you'll know how to prevent it.

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to find out what's going wrong and where. Its probably going to be much quicker than us going through your code.

Comment: I tried debugger and I do understand what is out of bounds exception is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
 if(i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] == mat[i+k][j]){
        return 1 + pathCount(mat,i+k,j);}
```

what will it be, if **i+k>=mat.length**? Or,

```
if(j < mat[i].length-1 && mat[i][j]==mat[i][j+k]+1){
        return 1 + pathCount(mat,i,j+k);
```

what will it be, if **j+k>=mat[i].length**? Or,

```
if(i > 0 && mat[i][j]==mat[i-k][j]){
        return 1 + pathCount(mat,i-k,j);}
```

what will it be, if **i-k<0**? Or,

```
if(j > 0 && mat[i][j]==mat[i][j-k]){
        return 1 + pathCount(mat,i,j-k);}
```

what will it be, if **j-k<0**?

Handle these cases as well. See, being **i>0**, still **i-k** can be less than or equal to **0**. This is the trick in your case.

Hope you got it now.

**Edit:**
After you editing your code still it is getting the same exception as you are accessing the indexes and then checking if the index is a valid one.

Not this:

```
if(i < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] == mat[i+k][j] && i+k < mat.length-1)
```

Instead, you must write:

```
if(i < mat.length-1 && i+k < mat.length-1 && mat[i][j] == mat[i+k][j])
```

Same for others as well.

By doing this, you will be able to get rid of **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

Comment: tried to fix the cases you mentioned but still more of the same problem.

Comment: Then your code should be ok now.

Comment: Isn't your code working now? @user3451179

Comment: still going out of bounds... trying other ways

Comment: Edited my answer, as well. @user3451179